# The best way to know which fragment we navigated from

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, fragment

Im writing an application which uses a lot of Fragments (with ViewModels). I'm using Navigation Component with nav graph to navigate from one fragment to another by using

`findNavController().navigate(R.id.myFragment)`

In some cases I navigate throught the fragments quite often and without any static dependencies.
You can go like F1->F2->F3->F4 but you can also go as F1->F2->F4->F3

For example when we navigate to F4, I need to know which fragment was before that, was it F3 or F2?
I managed to workaround for now by sending to F4 a `arguments Bundle()` with `arguments.putBoolean("fromFragment3",true)` and `arguments.getBoolean("fromFragment3")` but that just seems ugly and you can quickly mess up the whole code.

**Question:**

What's the best way to know which Fragment were the user before navigating to current fragment?

Comment: why don't you want to create a global List and store there all fragments queue? something like backstack

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `addOnDestinationChangedListener` and listen fragments transactions :

```
 NavController navController= Navigation.findNavController(MainActivity.this,R.id.your_nav_host);

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onDestinationChanged: "+destination.getLabel());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Doesn't work it shows the current fragment label.